# I get the following message The uploaded file could not be moved to /home/reascom/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2012/07

Tags: themes, uploads

The uploaded file could not be moved to /home/reascom/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2012/07.

This is the message I get when I try to load anything to my existing web site.  images and themes get this message.

What should i do?

Comment: I'm having the same error, surprisingly it started suddenly, one day it was working and the other it wasn't. The permissions are set properly as well (0777)! Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the owner is not set right. try changing to 'www-data'

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions in your wp-content/uploads folder (and subfolders) - the web server needs to be able to write to it.